# localStorage R/W performance?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a certain amount of services that rely on the localStorage (write/read/remove). I would like to know about the performance of the localStorage (time needed for every operation) and the extreme case where I should put some sort of a timeout.

Comment: The performance bottleneck probably is not the writing itself, but serializing your data.

Comment: what stop you to create  highload testing and tell us about results?

Comment: from what I have seen sometimes when I need to remove some item it more or less than 500 ms . is it because my local storage is full of other variables or the operation itself takes a time to operate.